# Unable to access props inside a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I currently have the following code:

```
const Suggestions = ({ suggestions }) => {
  return (
    suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => <p key={i}>{suggestion}</p>)
  )
}
```

But I somehow want to be able to render all of the `p` tags inside a div. So, my final code after the mapping would look something like:

```
<div className="suggestions">
    <p>suggestion1</p>
    <p>suggestion2</p>
          ...
</div>
```

So I tried something like this:

```
const Suggestions = ({ suggestions }) => {
  return (
     <div className="suggestions">
        suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => <p key={i}>{suggestion}</p>)
     </div>
  )
}
```

But this says `suggestions` and `i` isn't defined. Why am I not able to access the prop inside my div element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your map with  curly braces:

```
const Suggestions = ({ suggestions }) => {
  return (
     <div className="suggestions">
        {suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => <p key={i}>{suggestion}</p>)}
     </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

export const Suggestions = ({ suggestions }) => {
  return (
     <div className="suggestions">
      {suggestions && suggestions.map((item, i) => (<p key={i}> {item} </p>))}
     </div>
  )
}

export const App = () => {
  const list = ['test1', 'test2','test3'];
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <Suggestions suggestions={list} />
    </div>
  );
}
```